# Rails database configuration does not specify adapter. What do I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

The following is the error message:

```
/Users/davidzabner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection'
    /Users/davidzabner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
    ...
    /Users/davidzabner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    /Users/davidzabner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
    /Users/davidzabner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    /Users/davidzabner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

My database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

gem 'mini_magick'
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't copy in all of the error message?

Comment: Show us the `gem` file as well, please.

Comment: Is that how your database configuration is, without newlines? That would definitely be your issue if it is.

Comment: @DouglasFShearer it was just formatting, I edited it.

Comment: Can you evaluate the `Rails.env` and report that back here? e.g. place a "`throw Rails.env` in `environment.rb`? Most often these errors occur when you are running Rails in a (custom) environment that is not defined in the database.yml.

Comment: The top of my error message is: rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter

Comment: @NW0428  Please in the next time use the formatters available, to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: @berkes it now throws "uncaught throw 'local'"

Comment: NWH: that means you are running rails in the environment called "local", which, indeed you haven't set in your database.yml. Now, please tell us how you are running Rails.

Comment: Are you running in production mode ? You Gemfile shows gem 'pg' in production, while your database.yml shows sqlite3

Answer (score 10):

I solved a similar problem in a somewhat intricate project. Not sure it's directly related, but I'm posting this as the way of debugging the problem may be helpful.

In my case, I had the following scenario:

- The situation only occurred when `RAILS_ENV=production`. When I did `RAILS_ENV=development` it worked. Weirdly enough, when I changed the `production` entry in `database.yml` to `production2` and ran the command with `RAILS_ENV=production2`, it worked.
- In the project I was connecting to multiple database connections through various models and libraries.

Here is what I did to detect the issue:

`vim /Users/davidzabner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb`

(or wherever the backtrace is telling you the issue is).

Then, I found the place in the code that has these lines:

```
def resolve_hash_connection(spec) # :nodoc:
  spec = spec.symbolize_keys

  raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "database configuration does not specify adapter") unless spec.key?(:adapter)
```

And changed it to the following:

```
def resolve_hash_connection(spec) # :nodoc:
  spec = spec.symbolize_keys

  # Debug printing
  puts "*" * 80, spec.inspect, "*" * 80

  raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "database configuration does not specify adapter") unless spec.key?(:adapter)
```

Then I reran the command, in my case `bundle exec rails c production`.

By doing this I realized that Rails wasn't looking for the `production` entry as I was thinking it was. It was looking for a different entry called `abc_production`, which was required in my project due to the multiple database connections I was referring to earlier. On that particular server someone forgot to add that `abc_production` entry to `database.yml`. Adding the entry solved the issue.

I believe it happened only when `RAILS_ENV=production` because in `environments/production.rb` I have `config.eager_load = true`, which means Rails will eager-load the application and classes to memory, and probably attempt to establish all database connections defined in those classes (one of them being `abc_production`).

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation... If you're not using multiple connections, try and debug the problem by changing `connection_specification.rb` and see if it gives you any lead..

Comment: This identify what environment was being called and helped me solve my issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

i don't now exactly what you tried to do but.

currently i got the same error as i tried to run < rails c -e production > with ruby-2.10.

> `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

as i run < rails c production > everything works.

maybe this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with **staging** environment and I did:

1. added devise secret to devise.rb initializer file
2. configured staging 'secret_key_base' in secrets.yml

It worked fine me there after.

Answer (score 0):

I've crated an gist with a sample database configuration, please make sure you use it.
The gist is located at: https://gist.github.com/fidalgo/5970617

Also make sure you run rake `db:setup` to setup your database.

Also since in your environment you are using Sqlite for production and test too, in your Gemfile change this lines:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

to

```
#group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
#end
```

it shouldn't make any significant difference, except you are using other environment than development.

Comment: None of those things helped. Thanks for the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too. I tried all similar questions I can find but none of them resolved my problem then I tried to print configurations system read from database.yml in `activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb`

```
def resolve_string_connection(spec) # :nodoc:
  hash = configurations.fetch(spec) do |k|
    connection_url_to_hash(k)
  end
  p configurations
  p spec
  raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "#{spec} database is not configured") unless hash

  resolve_hash_connection hash
end
```

The output is

```
{"production"=>nil, "  adapter"=>"mysql2", "  encoding"=>"utf8mb4", "  username"=>"myUsername", "  password"=>"myPassword", "  pool"=>5, "  database"=>"mydb", "  host"=>"myHost", "  port"=>3306, "mydb_production"=>nil}
```

So my problem is there's something wrong in the database.yml causes YAML parse error. However I don't find anything wrong by my bare eyes so I copied a file from another server then problem resolved.

Hope this can help someone :p

Answer (score 0):

Realise this is a little old, but have just come across whilst looking for an answer on a similar issue.  Just wanted to point out that you still have sqlite3 as your adaptor in your .yml.  As you have probably found out since, Heroku does not allow sqlite3 as a production db. [SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)